# What is the difference between "kill -0" and "kill -9"?

Tags: shell, kill

Please explain the difference of above them. "kill -0" and "kill -9"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because `man kill` and `google man kill signal` is there too.

Comment: `man kill` on my system does not  say what signal 0 does.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169899/55635

kill(1)

```
$ man 1 kill
...
If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.
...
```

kill(2)

```
$ man 2 kill
...
If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed; 
this can be used to check for the existence of a process ID or process 
group ID.
...
```

So signal 0 will not actually in fact send anything to your process's PID, but will in fact check whether you have permissions to do so.

While `kill -9` - actually sends SIGKILL to PID